# Spring Boot 2.7.1 LetsEncrypt PEM keystore throws Resource location must not be null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

So I read that Spring Boot now supports PEM since 2.7.0

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.webserver.configure-ssl  17.3.7. Configure SSL

So I am using PEM generated by certbot.

My application.properties

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring1.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
server.port=443
server.ssl.certificate=fullchain1.pem
server.ssl.certificate.certificate-private-key=privkey1.pem
server.ssl.trust-certificate=fullchain1.pem
```

When I launch I get

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 'null'

Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 'null'

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null

Comment: you are missing `classpath` in your properties file for file location.

Comment: files are outside of JAR so that is not needed

Comment: server.ssl.certificate must point to certificate and the server.ssl.certificate-private-key=privkey1.pem must be like this , no need trust store and due spring boot bug server.ssl.key-store-password=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation [SSL configuration springboot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.webserver.configure-ssl)

**UPDATE:**

> Adding the content from link to directly in the answer, as link can
> get updates
>
> SSL can be configured declaratively by setting the various
> server.ssl.* properties, typically in application.properties or
> application.yml. The following example shows setting SSL properties
> using a Java KeyStore file:
>
> ```
> server.port=8443
> server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
> server.ssl.key-store-password=secret
> server.ssl.key-password=another-secret
> ```
>
> The following example shows setting SSL properties using PEM-encoded
> certificate and private key files:
>
> ```
> server.port=8443
> server.ssl.certificate=classpath:my-cert.crt
> server.ssl.certificate-private-key=classpath:my-cert.key
> server.ssl.trust-certificate=classpath:ca-cert.crt
> ```

Your properties are not correctly declared,

`server.ssl.certificate.certificate-private-key=privkey1.pem` should be changed to `server.ssl.certificate-private-key=privkey1.pem`

Comment: Thanks in the end working variant is server.ssl.certificate=cert1.pem
server.ssl.certificate-private-key=privkey1.pem
server.ssl.key-store-password=

Answer (score 0):

So this workaround works

```
@Configuration
public class SSLConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() throws Exception {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        Ssl ssl = new Ssl();
        ssl.setEnabled(true);
        ssl.setCertificate("cert1.pem");
        ssl.setCertificatePrivateKey("privkey1.pem");
        ssl.setKeyStoreType("PKCS12");
        ssl.setKeyStorePassword(""); // without this decrytption fails
        factory.setSsl(ssl);
        factory.setPort(443);

        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to do this I suppose, just correct the property accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
server.ssl.key-store=file:///Users/...
```

Have you tried this way of setting the path? First, make sure your application up with the correct path, then dig into the next step.

Comment: which of 4 letsencrypt pem files should I set as key-store